# NSURLConnection memory keeps increasing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsurlconnection

The following code triggers a request every 4 seconds.

```
aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:printUrl];
request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];

//MAKE REQUEST
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"h=%@&app=%@v%@&ios=true", hash,iosVersion,version];
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

_connectionFetch = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I am using ARC and I'm pretty new to obj c. You can easily see the memory increase when you call the nsurlconnection very often:

```
for (int i = 0; i<=10; i++) {
   _connectionFetch = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];     
}
```

In the delegates didFailWithError,didReceiveData,didReceiveResponse,connectionDidFinishLoading I'm releasing the variabel with

```
_connectionFetch = nil;
```

I'm also clearing the cache and disabled it:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];
```

The problem now is, that after some time the logic which triggers the URL fetching stops working. Probably because of too much memory assigned. The memory is increasing periodically:
[image]